# Rate my Application in iTunes within my Application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, itunes

I have to provide a link in my app where the user touches on it it will take me to the itunes Appstore page of my application where the user can rate the Application. I think other apps try to access the Appstore Application in the device and pass the corresponding url of the application in itunes... How to do this? Any ideas...

Comment: A small hint for future trespassers here. Appirater is a piece of code that can do this functionality in a easy way. Get this here http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/appirater. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's my method; this goes straight to the App Store and to the Review/Rate page for my app:

```
- (IBAction)rateGame {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=409954448"]];
}
```

Just change the id at the end (409954448) to the id for your app. Also, if you track the launch count or something, you can trigger this method after, say 12 launches to increase ratings. I added this in my update and in about 2 weeks it generated 5 ratings. Very useful.

Comment: Why was this downvoted (I upvoted to nullify)? It takes you directly to the review page, and is exactly what I use in my own apps. This is the optimal solution...

Answer (score 6):

```
NSURL* urlToMyApp = @"http://url.to.my/app/in/the/app/store";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlToMyApp];
```

Comment: Note that you have to actually have an app store URL to do this, so you'd normally put it in on an app update.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use,

See link below, It will redirect you on app store app details page.
StoreKit.framework not needed.

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-add-write-a-review-rate-us-feature-to-your-app/

Notes :

- If iOS >= 7 use, [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idYOUR_APP_ID"]]];
- This will not work on simulator so don't test on Simulator :-)