# How to add Rate App To Unlock Something

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app and I want to have a image pop up saying rate app to unlock something and if they rate the app or have done it earlier for something in my game to change.

1. How do make it so if they click the button it takes them to my app page in the App Store?
2. How do I make it so the game checks if they have rated my app every time they use it?
   And if they did how do I say run this method or do this if they rated it?

Thanks

Comment: Use a UIButton which you can use to code your unlock if clicked. As for app store rating, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838674/rate-my-application-in-itunes-within-my-application-in-iphone

Comment: Can't be done. You can take the user to the app store for your app but you can't verify whether they actually rate the app or not. And it's unlikely that Apple would approve such a thing any way.

Comment: DON'T DO THIS! I HATE THE IDEA OF FORCING USERS TO RATE AN APP! IF I DOWNLOADED YOUR APP AND IT DID THIS, THE NEXT THING I WOULD DO IS DELETE THE APP!!!! ARGH!  N.B. EVEN JUST ASKING FOR A RATING IS BAD ENOUGH! (P.S. Sorry for shouting but that just shows how passionate I am about this. Please don't do it.)

Comment: Can't be done. But if it could… **don't do it**. It's a terrible user experience.

Comment: A lot of top apps on the app store do this. As an indie dev, I know there are a lot of people who can't or won't buy in-app purchases or don't even have a credit card. In this case, it's nice for them to continue using the app by writing a review.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no way to check if user rated your app**.

The only thing you can do is to open the `AppStore` app with a page of your application. However, if user rates your app there or not, remains unknown and you cannot know it.

To open `AppStore` app with your app page:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.com/apps/appname"]];
```

or like this:

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id284417350?mt=8";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Comment: It's also a terrible user experience that's pretty close to blackmail.

Comment: Well, there's no such things as free, which is why Apple is changing their wording from "FREE" to "GET". It costs a lot of money to make an app, and as an Indie developer, let me tell you, it's HARD making a living from apps. Giving the user a choice between writing a review or deleting the app, well that seems like a no brainer to me.